# HTML won't let me make a font size larger than 36

Tags: html

So I need to enlarge the current title of a webpage I am working on.  It is currently set at 36.  I can lower the size just fine, but whenever I raise it above 36, the font just sticks at 36.  Here is the code currently set to size 48 but still showing up at 36 when it's displayed.

```
<div align="center">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>      
      <td bgcolor="22595F"><div style="text-align: center;"></br><font face="Arial" color="white" size="48">1867 Settlement</font><p></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: that is size not font size try `style = "font-size:48px;"` btw [<font>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is Obsolete

Comment: Tried adding that in the div field and it just ignores it as well and changes the font to the default size.  How can I do this inline?  I don't have a stylesheet or time to redo the whole thing with one.

Comment: Also ignores it when placed in span.

Comment: I even tried adding an extra style in CSS at the top of the page with 48px, applied this to the title and all it did was make the banner area larger.  It still remains stuck at size 36.

Comment: Try checking the page in developer console of the browser and see what styles, from where, are really applied when it is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp
"

### Definition and Usage

The  tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

Comment: How can I do it inline then?  This is an old website with no style sheet and I don't have the time or technical knowledge to basically go back and rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: em, i don't get it, you want it to be just bigger? to have bigger font just add <div style="text-align: center; font: 50px Arial; color:white;"> and remove the font tag. Sorry, can you explain a little more what you want?

Comment: I just read what you've written under the question. To begin with if you don't want the enlargement  as the font get's bigger remove the <br /> and <p> tag inside that div, use margin-top and margin-bottom instead.

Comment: Also try font-size: 50 !important and see if it works

Comment: <div style="text-align: center; font:50px Arial !important;">1867 Settlement</div>